# Please help me install this game

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I bought Fallout New Vegas recently (retail) and decided to install it today. I'll cut right to it. I don't have WIFI I used my phone's data to register the game and then tried to install the game via disc. However, when I do this the game shoots to Steam downloads and starts downloading. I have no idea how to force a disc install if that's even a thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just can't. Nowadays games don't fit on discs so they always redirect you to steam to download it

Comment: I have done it before. I bought the new devil may cry and installed it via disc perfectly all I had to do was register it. And that was yesterday.

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959559-fallout-new-vegas/57128921

Comment: Shot I will attempt this in about an hour. Car needs to go in! Thanks

Comment: @Ise why not post that as an answer (summarize the link)? I find that you like to leave potential answers as comments a lot.  Be brave and go for it! ☺

Comment: Yep sorry it's true that I always leave comments first ... ^^' I'll summarize it in an answer then :)

Answer (score 6):

- Activate Product with Steam
- Right click on the game in steam and choose to delete local content (this will stop the download)
- Leave Steam open (don't end the process/executable)
- Open the setup from the disk
- Choose to install

After the install, in steam, you will notice that it is downloading but do not worry it's only updating 
(You can go into the game properties and mark "no auto update")

If that **does not work** then try the following :

- Make sure that Steam is off
- Allow auto install

And if neither of them do work then here is another way : [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959559-fallout-new-vegas/56810507)

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959559-fallout-new-vegas/57128921)

Comment: Sorted! Thank you so much that worked great! Now if you'll excuse me I have a wasteland to explore xP

Comment: @KennyKillswitch be sure to accept answers that you have found useful and helped to solve your problem.  Welcome to Arqade!